# platformBuildVersionCode / platformBuildVersionName being set to the same as versionCode / versionName

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So I believe that platformBuildVersionCode  / platformBuildVersionName should be set to the target SDK, however when we build our application they are being set to the same as versionCode / versionName?

Has anyone seen this issue?

```
<manifest
    versionCode='2'
    versionName='2.0'
    compileSdkVersion='28'
    compileSdkVersionCodename='9'
    package='com.bla.ftg'
    platformBuildVersionCode='2'
    platformBuildVersionName='2.0'>
```

We do set the versionName and code in the manifest.

Comment: I have the same issue and I think it's causing amazon to reject my app: I just get "Invalid input" in their dashboard.
I am setting everything in gradle